# PostgreSQL UNION ignore duplicates for only specific columns

Tags: sql, database, postgresql

I have posts table and notifications table. I want the posts which are also in notifications table to be scored as 999999 instead of their orijinal score. The following query gives the result in the picture. Red's are unionized by notification and the rest are from posts. As you can see even though they are unionized blues are duplicate since the score is different `UNION` doesn't count them as duplicates. How can I make them count as duplicates and only allow red ones.

[image]

`UNION` and `UNION ALL` gives the same result since I'm changing the objects score value for the notification part of the union. I tried `DISTINCT ON (id)` but it doesn't allow to be sorted over score and `DISTINCT ON (id,score)` sorts it wrong.

```
SELECT id, created_at, data, (data->>'score')::NUMERIC AS score
FROM posts
WHERE NOT EXISTS (
    SELECT 1
    FROM swipes
    WHERE ((swipes.data)->>'post_id')::INT = posts.id
      AND ((swipes.data)->>'user_id')::INT = 32)

UNION

SELECT DISTINCT ON (id) ((notifications.data)->>'post_id')::INT AS id, posts.created_at, posts.data, 9999999 AS score
FROM notifications, posts
WHERE ((notifications.data)->>'user_id')::INT = 32 AND posts.id = ((notifications.data)->>'post_id')::INT

ORDER BY score DESC
```

Is there a way to allow `UNION` check duplications only `id` column?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use CTE:

```
with CTE as ( your query without order by )
Select id, created_at, data, max(score) as score
from cte
Group by id, create_at, data
Order by ...
```